# What is the difference between a Zero-inflated negative binomial regression and a Heckman-two-step regression model?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, heckman

The title of my question says pretty much what I'm struggling to understand: 
What is the difference between a Zero-inflated negative binomial (ZINB) regression and a Heckman-two-step regression model?
I get that the ZINB is for count data and the Heckit model usually goes with censored data. 
I still don't understand the difference. Both account for an overinflation of 0 and allow the calculation for the probability of getting a 0 on the dependent variable.

Are there advantages and disadvantages (especially when dealing with development aid data)?

I would greatly appreciate any explanation!

Comment: can you provide a link to a description of the Heckmann-two-step regression model? I only find sources that refer to the Heckman Two-Step Correction for Selection Bias which is quite obviously something else than a negative-binomial regression.

Comment: Its also known as Heckit model -> its a generalization of a Tobit model if I understood that correctly.

Comment: Never heard of "Heckit".   But to the question, the Heckman two-stage model, which uses a logistic or probit binary model in the first stage, allows for arbitrary clumping at zero.  Zero-inflated single models can only inflate P(zero) so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the Heckit model is supposed to model data that is zero-inflated due to sample bias while the distribution of the population is not zero-inflated, while the zero-inflated negative binomial regression is used if the true distribution of the population is actually zero-inflated. As a conclusion, the Heckit model and the zero-inflated negative binomial regression are not alternatives to each other but suitable for completely different situations.

The following two citations nicely wrap this up:

> Theoretically the standard Tobit model is applicable only if the
>   underlying dependent variable contains negative values that have been
>   censored to zero in the empirical realization of the variable.  In
>   practice, though, the Tobit modelis routinely employed when the values
>   of the observed dependent variable are exclusively nonnegative and are
>   clustered at zero, irrespective of whether any censoring has
>   occurred. The Heckit model has emerged as the de facto default
>   alternative to Tobit when values cluster at zero due to selection bias rather than censoring, but applications of the Heckit model have proven problematic as well.

Sigelman, L., & Zeng, L. (1999). Analyzing Censored and Sample-Selected Data with Tobit and Heckit Models. Political Analysis, 8(2), 167-182. doi:10.1093/oxfordjournals.pan.a029811

> The zero-inflated negative binomial (ZINB) regression is used for
>   count data that exhibit overdispersion and excess zeros. The data
>   distribution combines the negative binomial distribution and the logit
>   distribution.  The possible values of Y are the nonnegative integers:
>   0, 1, 2, 3, and so on.

From the NCSS Statistical Software (Developers of PASS Sample Size) Chapter 328. [Link](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Zero-Inflated_Negative_Binomial_Regression.pdf).